# Why does the internet think Microsoft Edge is Google Chrome?

Tags: google, browsers, google-chrome, microsoft, browser-detecting

I am currently using Microsoft Edge.  Edge is the new Internet Browser from Microsoft.

I tried running a Unity3D Program in Edge, and it gave me the error that it was not available in Chrome:

[image]

Then I tried running a Browser Test at BrowserScore.com, and the test gave me the results for the Chrome browser:

[image]

Why?

Comment: Why do you think Microsoft Edge thinks its Chrome? from the evidence your provided its the completely opposite.  If you think that your user agent is not correctly reporting the correct browser then you should check it by http://whatsmyuseragent.com/ or a similar service. Edge is new, expect websites to get confused.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because Microsoft Edge presents a User-Agent string that contains the word Chrome. And, for that matter, Safari.

Check out http://whatsmyuseragent.com/ and you'll see something like this:

[image]
(Emphasis mine)

This is deliberate on Microsoft's behalf to fool naïve user-agent checks into thinking that it's not Internet Explorer. Which it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple and here is an oversimplified example:

```
// Your browser is identifying itself as this
$ua_string = 'EDGE';

// The website logic is this
if($ua_string === 'IE')
{
    echo 'You are using IE';
}
elseif($ua_string === 'FIREFOX')
{
    echo 'You are using Firefox';
}
else
{
    echo 'You are using Chrome, and we don\'t support that.';
}
```

Comment: Your example has a syntax error. ;)